# Facebook SDK failed binder transaction error

Tags: android, facebook, bundle

When a Test Developer runs my app on his phone he gets a "Failed Binder Transaction" error in the logcat. Does this error cause problems?

One feature of my app is that it shows the Facebook friends who have downloaded the app. But the friends list is empty even though the Test Developer has the app (and I'm friends with the tester on Facebook)

So I came to the conclusion that the reason I am not seeing the tester in my friends list is because of this Failed Binder Transaction error.

Can someone please tell me if this is a correct conclusion - meaning once I fix the Binding error I should see his name on my friends list?

Or perhaps this is not the reason my friends list is blank. I might have coded something incorrectly.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: anybody have experience with this issue?

Comment: I don't think the "Failed Binder Transaction" is related. /me/friends will give you friends who have also logged into your app via FB, but you also need the user_friends permission.

Comment: I read the user_friends permission is added by default. and what is /me/friends? Can u link me to that api?

Comment: Ah i see. I need to ask for user_friends permission at Login! ok i will try to do that. But can you still show me what /me/friends is?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends

Comment: solved my issue finally. All I had to was add these two lines in SplashFragment.java:         
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button); loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
So at least it's good to know Failed Binder Transaction does not effect the outcome (so far)